# Std::Vector Memory Access Violation

Tags: c++, memory, vector, stdvector, access-violation

I'm writing an email extract function to get emails from some html.
Halfway through I started getting some memory access violation errors,
I used breakpoints to find where the crash started and commented the line that causes the memory access violation.
Someone please help me solve my error :) Thanks!
Here is the code:

```
void extractEmail(const char* html)
{
    std::string htmls = html;
    int pos = 0;
    int amountOfEmails = 0;
    std::vector<int> emailAtPoints;
    std::vector<int> startOfEmail;
    std::vector<int> endOfEmails;
    while(pos != -1)
    {
        pos = htmls.find("@",pos+1);
        if(pos == -1)
            break;
        emailAtPoints.push_back(pos);
        amountOfEmails++;
    }
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator itr = emailAtPoints.begin(); itr != emailAtPoints.end(); ++itr)
    {
        std::cout << "There was found an @ sign at: " << *itr << std::endl;
    }
    pos = 0;
    unsigned int current = 0;
    while(pos != -1)
    {
        // Get position for start of email
        pos = htmls.rfind(" ",emailAtPoints.at(current)+1);
        if(pos == -1)
            break;
        startOfEmail.push_back(pos); // Add to vector
        // Get position for end of email
        pos=htmls.find(" ",emailAtPoints.at(current)+1);
        if(pos == -1)
        {
            startOfEmail.pop_back(); // Destroy last element.
            break;
        }
        endOfEmails.push_back(pos); // Add
        if(current < emailAtPoints.size())
            current++;
        else
            break;
    }
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator itr = startOfEmail.begin(); itr != startOfEmail.end(); ++itr) // This thing crashes it --- Memory Access Violation
    {
        std::cout << "The numbers for where every email starts at: " << *itr << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator itr = endOfEmails.begin(); itr != endOfEmails.end(); ++itr)
    {
        std::cout << "The numbers for where every email ends   at: " << *itr << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "done";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The strings needs to be pointed to the CSS script, which they don't seem to be. You also didn't compile the CMS in the front header, which is pretty much essential for any code of this type to work.

Also, I would edit the strings so that they're able to decode the int currents. The way you made it is extremely clumsy and there's a lot of unecessary code.

I would also change this:

```
 {
    pos = htmls.find("@",pos+1);
    if(pos == -1)
        break;
    emailAtPoints.push_back(pos);
    amountOfEmails++;
```

Into this

```
 {
    pos = htmls.find("@",pos+1);
    if(pos == -1)
      point cssthings
      execute defluxinator
        break;
    emailAtPoints.push_back(pos);
    amountOfEmails++;
```

Hope I helped. Good luck :)

Comment: Could anyone please give me a serious answer?